# Personalizar grafico con jqplot

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tengo este grafico con la libreria jqplot
[image: GRAFICO]

Este es el codigo:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var qr = [
        [1, 5, null],
        [4, 2, null],
        [6, 5, '2'],
        [4, 5, '3'],
        [0, 5, null],
        [4, 5, '3'],
        [6, 5, '2'],
        [4, 5, '3']
    ];
    var gr_html = $.jqplot('linegraph', [qr], {
        seriesDefaults: {
            showLine: false,
            markerRenderer: $.jqplot.MarkerRenderer,
            markerOptions: {
                size: 5
            }
        },
        series: [{
            pointLabels: {
                show: true,
            },
            markerOptions: {
                style: 'circle',
                size: 5,
            },
        }],
        axes: {
            xaxis: {
                label: 'Score',
                min: -10,
                max : 10
            },
            yaxis: {
                renderer: $.jqplot.canvasTextRenderer,
                label: 'Rate',
                labelRenderer: $.jqplot.CanvasAxisLabelRenderer,
                labelOptions: {
                    fontSize: '10pt'
                },
                min: -10,
                max : 10
            },
        }
    });
});
```

Me gustaria saber un par de cosas.

- Como hago para definir la separacion de los puntos de los ejes, es decir, que en vez de mostrar 10.0000, 6.6667 ... aparezca 10,9,8
- La otra es como divido el grafico en cuadrantes y que quede algo mas o menos asi

[image: Grafico 2]

Por ultimo quisiera añadir, que si no es posible hacer esto con `jqplot`, que alguien me diria con que libreria js puedo hacerlo (a poder ser que no sea d3, me parece demasiado compleja).

Answer (score 0):

tambien trabajo con gráficas `JqPlot`, me pasó que los datos de los ejes cuando las cifras son muy grandes se amontonan, mi solución fue hacerlas más pequeñas o quitarlas, de la siguiente manera:

En la linea del código de la gráfica poner "0", " exactamente en `fontSize: '0pt'` dentro de "xAXIS" o "YAXIS" ejemplo completo:

```
xaxis: 
{
    tickOptions: {

    fontSize: '0pt' //aquí va el tamaño del número
    },
```

Saludos